# How to export image in CRI-O?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, cri-o

Both docker and containerd provide golang clients and provide some interfaces, such as list images, export images or tag images. How can this be done in cri-o?
eg:
`github.com/containerd/containerd`
and
`github.com/docker/docker/client`

Answer (score 0):

it seemed logical to me that such an option would be present for such a simple need, searched around and it seems it's a wanted feature but not fulfilled as it seems by these issues [1](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/issues/438) [2](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/issues/640) [3](https://app.bountysource.com/issues/99987024-crictl-image-tag-and-image-push-support). there is some sense to this since crictl was destined to be a debugging to cri-o and not a container management tool.

from personal use, if you prefer switching from docker, [podman](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/) could be an option for such operations, it's a daemon-less alternative to docker and cri-o, and employs other opensource tools to achieve its goals:

[buildah](https://buildah.io/) - handles building and manipulating container images

[skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) - registry specific tasks relating to container images handling (probably the first candidate for your use case even by itself)

If you want to stick to the popular CLI commands **podman** is your guy, if you want to go as minimalist as possible, using **skopeo** directly could be an option

hope this helps you in your decision-making process ;)